# list vs observable comparison table

Tags: c#, .net, list, observablecollection

Is there a comparison table of "List vs Observable" and its performance comparision table? 
If a table does not exist I would like to know the differences between list and observable.

Comment: their difference can be easily found from google: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Comment: Yes, but there are only few difference and there is no performance comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Minor performance overhead from event firing and eventargs construction.

No AddRange() method.